# How to return all opposite pairs in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, match, dataframe

For the dataframe below, how to return all opposite pairs?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,-2,2,-1,-1,1,1], columns=['a'])

   a
0  1
1  2
2 -2
3  2
4 -1
5 -1
6  1
7  1
```

The output should be as below:

> (1) sum of all rows is 0
>   (2) as there are 3 "1" and 2 "-1" in
>   original data, output includes 2 "1" and 2"-1".

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2 -2
4 -1
5 -1
6  1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Seems OK to me.  If it's a duplicate can someone point to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought this would take fewer lines (and probably can) but this does work.  First just create a couple of new columns to simplify the later syntax:

```
>>> df1['abs_a'] = np.abs( df1['a'] )
>>> df1['ones'] = 1
```

Then the main thing you need is to do some counting.  For example, are there fewer `1`s or fewer `-1`s?

```
>>> df2 = df1.groupby(['abs_a','a']).count()

          ones
abs_a a       
1     -1     2
       1     3
2     -2     1
       2     2

>>> df3 = df2.groupby(level=0).min()

       ones
abs_a      
1         2
2         1
```

That's basically the answer right there, but I'll put it closer to the form you asked for:

```
>>> lst = [ [i]*j for i, j in zip( df3.index.tolist(), df3['ones'].tolist() ) ]
>>> arr = np.array( [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist] )

>>> np.hstack( [arr,-1*arr] )

array([ 1,  1,  2, -1, -1, -2], dtype=int64)
```

Or if you want to put it back into a dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame( np.hstack( [arr,-1*arr] ) )

   0
0  1
1  1
2  2
3 -1
4 -1
5 -2
```

Comment: Hi JohnE, thanks a lot for the help.
How do I return original index of those rows, instead of values? I only had one column of data in the original data to example to simplify things, but in reality there are other columns so I need the index to recover those. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, probably with a merge but there's a couple of complications:  (1) not unique identifiers so you'd have to come up with a way to fake that (sort first, then save index values), (2) you need a rule for which ones to drop.  For example, you need to drop one occurrence of "2", but which one?

Comment: If this solves most of your problem, you might want to move on and ask a new question regarding the remaining part (and specifying how  exactly you want to deal with issue #2 I mentioned in the prior comment).  I'm pretty sure it can be solved with a merge/join but just not sure exactly how to do it off the top of my head.